# How does the backend verify that the front-end is in fact the real front-end?

Tags: javascript, http, frontend, backend

**Beginner Question Here:** I am very new to fullstack development, and have been looking around at various beginner tutorials. One thing I do not really understand is how the backend and frontend "verify" that they are talking to each other. For example, if in a tutorial someone hosts the backend/api on Heroku, and the frontend on Netlify, how does the backend know that the get/post/put/delete request it is getting is actually coming from the legitimate frontend - and not some 3rd party who has tapped into it.

In the tutorials I am referencing the frontend is always told the URL of the backend API, but it never seems the backend is told where the frontend is, and where the requests will be coming from. I know this isn't the case, but it seems to me that anyone could just execute frontend code which triggers the backend into deleting/editing contents from the connected database.

If it would be easier to explain to me how this concept works, with an actual code-base you can reference - I'll link a tutorial I am slightly confused about below.

Tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aibtHnbeuio

Code from Tutorial: https://github.com/adrianhajdin/project_mern_memories

**Any explanations would be of great help. Thanks in advance**

Comment: you can disallow all other domains except the legitimate domain in CORS configuration. and also all the api's related to writing data should be protected by jwt or any other authentication method.

Comment: Links to code are not proper on Stack Overflow. I don't think this question needs code, so you could probably remove the last 4 paragraphs (we [don't need thanks either](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950/194720)).

Comment: There are many, many options for security infrastructure that will allow only a specific frontend to talk to a particular backend. One of the things that bothers me about tutorial writers is that they typically gloss over security because it's hard, and often specific to the workplace. But I think it should be part of every aspect of a developer's journey. Getting used to dealing with CORS and JWT, as @anees alludes to, can take a while and the earlier the better. Same with PKI and certificates. It's not difficult; just takes a little time to explain.